# CSS styles are missing when I convert a HTML page to PDF using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, html, itext

I have a html page with Inline styles, containing few `</br>` tags and `div` tags also two `tables`, 
I am usinh ITextSharp-5 version.

I have converted my `HTML` page to `PDf` using `ItextSharp`. The problem here is, the final `PDF` document which is converted is not having the exact style of HTML page . Below is my code for conversion.

```
var htmlFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Templates/GIPConversion.HTML"));
 StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlFile.ToString());

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();

            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();

             bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
```

Please let me know If I am missing anything while conversion, My final output should be same as my HTML page.

Thanks .

Comment: Maybe you are not using inline CSS.

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of iText, and maybe you are using `HTMLWorker` which is known to have very incomplete HTML&CSS support. Maybe you should use iText 7 + pdfHTML?

Comment: @Amedee, as you said  I have used Itext7 and pdfHTML and I have used HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument method for conversion, but my problem is there is an image in the HTML page which I am converting, so my final output is not containing that image... Please help me out with this

Comment: I can't see your HTML, did you forget to add it to your question?